# Text outside div while animating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please check this out: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dyft6zs6/

i'm trying to create a couple of boxes; first one will contain some text and second one an image.

Before animation, text adapts itself to the width of the div and goes out of containing div. Can anyone guide me? Many thanks.

```js
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.myfunction = function() {
      $('#col1').toggleClass('span12 span3');
      $('#col2').toggleClass('span0 span9');
   }; 
});

$('#cont').on('hover', function(){
      $('#col1').toggleClass('span12 span3');
      $('#col2').toggleClass('span0 span9');
});


CSS:
```

```css
.row-fluid div {
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
}

.row-fluid .span0 {
    width: 0%;
}

#col1 {
    background-color: #A6BFBA;
}

#col2 {
    background-color: #DE4124;
}

#trig {
    margin: 50px;
}

.row-fluid .span0 + [class*="span"]{
    margin-left: 0;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid" id="cont">
        <div id="col2" class="span0">
            <p>some textsome textsome textsome texts</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col1" class="span12">
            <img src="http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/29408" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*replace the width of .row-fluid .span0 {width: 0;} to */


.row-fluid .span0 {
width:auto;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that modification didn't do what i'm expecting. Any other suggestion comes to your mind? cheers.